# Where MVC 4 registered user are stored?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC 4 Web application but I'm having a problem about where registered users are stored.

I mean: when you access the website, you can enter the Register Form and register yourself to the website. Now: where those informations are stored? On a database ore somewhere else? I've been looking on the web but can't find anything that makes me understand. This is necessary for me because I need to access those data (registerd users) from another device so, my questions are:

- Where registerd users information are store?
- Which is the best solution to access those information from another device, for example a 
  Windows Phone application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an MVC-specific question. But yes if you want users to be able to register a new account on your website and login at a later date, then you need to store user data in a database of some sort.

If you want that stored user data to be accessible by different devices (especially phones) then make it available via an MVC 4 web API service.